# (Rudin) Uniqueness of Haar measure's proof

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, fourier-analysis, proof-explanation, haar-measure

The following is extracted from 'Fourier Analysis on Groups' by Rudin, page $2.$

> If $m$ and $m^{\prime}$ are two Haar measures on $G,$ then $m^{\prime} = \lambda m,$ where $\lambda$ is a positive constant.

Proof:

Fix $g \in C_c(G)$ so that 
$$\int_G g dm = 1.$$
Define $\lambda$ by 
$$\int_G g(-x)dm^{\prime}(x) = \lambda.$$
For any $f \in C_c(G),$ we then have 
\begin{align*}
\int_G fdm^{\prime} & = \int_G g(y)dm(y) \int_G f(x) dm^{\prime}(x) \\
& = \int_G g(y)dm(y) \int_G f(x+y) dm^{\prime}(x) \\
& = \int_G dm^{\prime}(x) \int_G g(y) f(x+y) dm(y) \\
& = \int_G dm^{\prime}(x) \int_G g(y-x) f(y) dm(y) \\
& = \int_G f(y) dm(y) \int_G g(y-x)dm^{\prime}(x) \\
& = \lambda \int_G f dm.
\end{align*}
Hence, $m^{\prime} = \lambda m.$
Note that the use of Fubini's theorem was legitimate in the preceding calculation, since the integrands $g(y) f(x+y)$ and $g(y-x)f(y)$ are in $C_c(G \times G).$

> Questions: 
>   $(1)$ Why the following equality holds 
>   $$\int_G g(y)dm(y) \int_G f(x+y) dm^{\prime}(x) = \int_G dm^{\prime}(x) \int_G g(y) f(x+y) dm(y)?$$
>   Since $f$ contains $y,$ I thought we cannot 'move' $f$ to left integral?
>
> $(2)$ How to use Fubini's theorem to obtain $$ \int_G dm^{\prime}(x)
>  \int_G g(y) f(x+y) dm(y)= \int_G dm^{\prime}(x) \int_G g(y-x) f(y)
>  dm(y)?$$
>
> $(3)$ Why  $$ \int_G g(y-x)dm^{\prime}(x)= \int_G
>  g(-x)dm^{\prime}(x) > 0?$$
>   I suppose the equality is due to translation invariant property of Haar measure? I have no idea on how to get $>0.$

Answer (score 3):

For Question 1, apply Fubini's Theorem to the double integral $\iint g(y)f(x-y)\ dm'(x)\,dm(y)$.  For Question 2, use the translation invariance of $m$, translating by $x$, to get $\int g(y)f(x+y))\,dm(y)=\int g(y-x)f(y)\,dm(y)$. For Question 3, I think $g$ should have been chosen to be non-negative at the beginning of the proof.  Then it's actually positive somewhere (since its $m$-integral is positive) and therefore bounded below by some positive $\epsilon$ on some nonempty open set (because it's continuous), and therefore has positive $m'$-integral (because a Haar measure gives every nonempty open set positive measure).